# Error: [X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:3895)

Tags: python, ssl, django-rest-framework, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a .crt file with root certificate in it and .key file. These are working fine with django-sslserver library. But recently I have added a new .crt file which contains domain, intermediate and the same old root certificate. Now when I am using this new certificate file with the key it is throwing "key value mismatch error".

I ran openssl commands on both the certs and the key to find the correct pair. None of them returned the same output. but I am able to use the old cert with root certificate and key without any issues

Comment: The private key does not depend on root CA or intermediate but on the leaf certificate.  Since you've changed this leaf certificate you need to also use the private key which is matching this certificate, i.e. you cannot simply use the key from the previous certificate. This will work only if the new certificate was deliberately created to reuse the same key, which seems to be not the case here. So use the private key which you've created when you created the new certificate.